# Create dynamic attribute in the Struct instance

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to create attribute dynamicaly in the `Struct` instance?

```
class Person < Struct.new(:name)
end

p = Person.new("Bilbo")
p[:surname] = "Jenkins" # does not work
```

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson Thanks for answer, but this not what I need. I gave the vote.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an `OpenStruct`:

```
require 'ostruct'

p = OpenStruct.new(name: "Bilbo")
p[:surname] = "Jenkins"

p.surname # => "Jenkins"
```

Comment: I got instance of Struct, and can't use OpenStruct.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass `Struct`, in which case you will be creating two classes, but it is more common to just create one:

```
Person = Struct.new(:name)

Person.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:name, :name=]

p = Person.new("Bilbo")
  #=> #<struct Person name="Bilbo">

Does `p` have an instance variable `@name` whose value is `"Bilbo"`?

p.instance_variables
  #=> []
```

No, it does not. Rather, it has "members":

```
p.members
  #=> [:name]
```

Can `name` be treated as an instance variable with the accessors provided by `Struct`?

```
p.name
  #=> "Bilbo"
p.name = "cat"
p.name
  #=> "cat"
```

Yes! That's because the members of a `Struct` instance are stored in array that you are not intended to access directly, only through the accessors.

Can we add `Struct` members dynamically? I don't know the answer to that, but methods are not provide to do that easily. Instead, just add instance variables and, optionally, accessors.

We can add an instance variable and set its value with:

```
p.instance_variable_set('@surname', 'Jenkins')
  #=> "Jenkins"

p.instance_variables
  #=> [:@surname]
```

and retrieve its value with:

```
p.instance_variable_get('@surname')
  #=> "Jenkins"
```

If you wish to create accessors for that variable, this is one way:

```
p.class.instance_eval do
  attr_accessor :surname
end

p.surname
  #=> "Jenkins"
p.surname = 'cat'
  #=> "cat"
p.surname
  #=> "cat"

p.class.instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:name, :name=, :surname, :surname=]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define new methods on your `Person` class by doing this:

```
Person.send(:define_method, :surname){@surname}
Person.send(:define_method, :surname=){|x|@surname=x}
```

I prefer `define_method` instead of `instance_eval` because I try to omit `eval` when possible.

Comment: In this case `size`, `values`, `members` methods will not work properly.

Comment: The `size`, `values`, and `members` will continue to work properly because they return information about the struct members; the new method is adding an instance variable, which is not a struct member, so doesn't affect `size`, `values`, and `members`.