# How to insert a new symbol into the instance of Class: BinData::Record in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am newbie in ruby. I have a instance of a `Class: BinData::Record`
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/dmendel/bindata/BinData/Record

```
class Message < BinData::Record
        endian  :big
        uint32 :header  
        uint16 :name
end
```

`meesage` is the instance of this class

```
message = Message.new
message.read('abcdefabcdef')
```

I want to add a new symbol into the instance, I tried below code

```
message.age = 10
```

But it doesn't work.

Could you please tell how to insert a new symbol into the instance of Class: BinData::Record?

Comment: You should really tell the readers where `BinData::Record` is coming from as its not vanilla Ruby or Rails.

Comment: Sorry. I thought it is ruby. https://www.rubydoc.info/github/dmendel/bindata/BinData/Record

Comment: Add it to the top of the question instead.

Comment: Done. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

It's better add new attributes to `Class` definition to use it:

```rb
class Message < BinData::Record
  uint32 :age # Add :age
end
```

There's no easy way to add new symbols to a instance.

If you have to do it, you could check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27701042/15097028